# notify listener not updating the UI

Tags: flutter, notify

Notifier class

```
class CategoryProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DocumentSnapshot? doc;
  String? selectedCategory;

  List<String> urlList = [];

  setCategory(selectedCat) {
    this.selectedCategory = selectedCat;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setCatSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    this.doc = snapshot;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  addImages(url) {
    this.urlList.add(url);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Widget that needs to be updated with new urlList

printing the length however gives the updated url list value

i did try by directly passing _provider.urlList yet the same issue

```
Widget loadGalary(BuildContext context) {
      print(_provider.urlList.length.toString());
      List<String> urlList = List.from(_provider.urlList);
      return GalleryImage(
        titileGallery: 'Galary',
        imageUrls: urlList,
      );
    }
```

Comment: Wrap `GalleryImage` inside a `Consumer` or `Selector`.

Comment: tried that yet having issues